# How to parse date string from database without time shift?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

I am getting `2016-07-13T00:00:00.000Z` string from database and converting it to MM/DD/YYYY format with moment.js like this:

```
result = moment('2016-07-13T00:00:00.000Z').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

which prints 07/12/2016 but I was expecting 07/13/2016. 
Local Linux timezone is America/New_York. `date` command prints this `Mon Jul  4 04:28:19 EDT 2016`

Comment: did you set the timezone properly in momentjs? http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Comment: No, I didn't. I see this requires installing a separate package.

Comment: What are you expecting? If you are expecting that date to be exactly the same, parse it with moment.utc(). See: https://maggiepint.com/2016/05/14/moment-js-shows-the-wrong-date/

Comment: Can you make this comment an answer? I'll pick it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date that you have is in UTC, as signified by the `z` at the end.

When you use the default moment constructor, `moment()`, it converts the time you pass it from the specified offset (in this case UTC) to the local time of the machine. This is why your date is changing. Because this is a UTC date, to keep it exactly the same you can use `moment.utc()`:

```
moment.utc('2016-07-13T00:00:00.000Z').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
"07/13/2016"
```

Alternately, parseZone would work as well:

```
moment.parseZone('2016-07-13T00:00:00.000Z').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
"07/13/2016"
```

For more information about all of the constructor functions in moment, see the [parsing guide](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/)
or [this blog post](https://maggiepint.com/2016/05/14/moment-js-shows-the-wrong-date/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use momentjs timezone : http://momentjs.com/timezone/

```
yourdate = moment.tz("2016-07-13T00:00:00.000Z", "America/New_York");
alert(yourdate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

This should give you the correct date in output.

Comment: `moment.tz('2016-07-13T00:00:00.000Z', 'America/New_York').format('MM/DD/YYYY');` still prints `'07/12/2016'`